# Why are my columns not resizing the way I want them to?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

OK, so here is the methodology of showing my form:

In the controller:

```
public void ShowView()
{
    Form1 View = new Form1();
    PopulateView();
    View.Show();
}

public static PopulateView(Form1 View)
{
    //get data to populate DataGridView....

    // AutoResizeColumns should resize columns, based on the content of the cells
    View.dgv1.AutoResizeColumns();

    // This method should resize any columns that aren't bigger than 100 (resized by AutoResizeColumns) to fit the column header instead.
    var columns = View.dgv1.Columns;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumns clm in columns)
    {
        if (clm.Width <= 100)
        {
            clm.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
        }
    }
}
```

However, neither of then are working as they should. `AutoResizeColumns` isn't resizing any columns, as the second method (`foreach` loop) is firing on all columns. Why is this? Is it because the form is being drawn *after* I have populated and resized the columns?

Comment: Try to move `View.dgv1.AutoResizeColumns();` to the bottom of your method and see if that helps.

Comment: I don't see how. Even if I remove the `foreach` loop, it still doesn't resize the columns.

Comment: If you move it after the `foreach`, then the columns will have an `AutoSizeMode`.  I'm not sure what it is by default... if it defaults to `ColumnHeader`, then there is no need for the loop.

Comment: Or, you could pass in `AllCells` as an argument to `AutoResizeColumns()` and drop the `foreach` altogether.  See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158594(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you can try the overloaded AutoResizeColumns method with the DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode argument.

Comment: @dubstylee setting the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` fixed it. I set it to `AllCells`, which fits each column to the Header or the Contents, whichever is bigger, so if you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @terrybozzio and I both mentioned in the comments above, you should be able to accomplish this by using the overloaded `AutoResizeColumns` method:

```
View.dgv1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

This should also allow you to remove the `foreach` loop and therefore simplify your method.

Comment: Yes, the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` method makes the `foreach` redundant. Thanks!